# C# weird assembly behaviour

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I experienced some weird assembly behaviour. I execute an invocation successful and my desired method gets executed, but this method cant access any `public static` values of objects of a `public static` class. All the values are `null` like if the method accesses an empty copy of the class, but thats impossible since the class is `static`.

To invoke the method i loaded the assembly like the following:

```
public static Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom( //path of the dll );
```

Then the invoked method can access only empty values from the other `static` class. But setting the `Assembly` as following enables the method to access all the values properly.

```
public static Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

I thought both of them are the same, because the `Assembly` i load from the directory is exactly the same as the one that gets executed at this time. An `if` comparison confirmed that those are *not* the same though. It seems that the `Assembly` loaded straight from the directory is not "initialised", so all its members are `null`. Can you please tell me what is going on there and why the ones `Assembly` members are all `null`.

Comment: I know that i cant have any instance of a `static` class. Imagine i have a `public static` property in my static class and i assign the value "whatever" to it. Now when i want to access this property from the invoked method, the value of the property is just `null`.

Comment: So you invoke some method from loaded assembly and that method receives nulls for static properties from the same assembly? Or you access those properties with reflection also?

Comment: "*you invoke some method from loaded assembly and that method receives nulls for static properties from the same assembly*" - exactly.

Comment: what is the runtime? which framework versions are being targeted?

Comment: @Mike The most recent one.

Comment: hmm, assume then it's net471 on windows...
I have two points here:
1. security, can workaround by using Load(byte[])
2. type initializer, can be enforced (type - the static class Type to initialize): System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle)

Comment: @Mike I understand what you are trying to do, but i dont undertstand your code at all. How can i initialise the type?

Comment: `Type type = typeof(Foo); System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConst‌​ructor(type.TypeHand‌​le);`

Comment: Hmm interesing. I did understand the idea what this code shell do, but it doesnt solve the problem as well, i just tried it. Because i cant run the constr in my invoke method. So either i call the run method ealier, but then it does not affect my invoke method and if i call it after it obviously doesnt change anything as well, so i just use it to my advantage. Anyway i found the problem though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since no one provided the desired answer, i´ll go for it. The issue i had there was basically a wrong understanding from `Assemblies`. The problem is that i loaded this `Assembly` right from the directory:

```
public static Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom( //path of the dll );
```

But this `Assembly` didnt get initialsed yet, it cointains the information about members and types, but not their values. Those are contained in the current executing `Assembly` which can be accessed this way:

```
public static Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

And in this current executing `Assembly` contains those assigned values for it´s members.

So `Assembly.LoadFrom()` can only be used if you need information about the types and members from this `Assembly` but not for invoking assigned values.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the constructor on the `static` class hasn't been called yet.

If you haven't called any methods on the `static` class, the constructor wouldn't have been called, and the fields on it wouldn't have been initialized.

If you're trying to access fields on it, you may want to try changing them to properties.

Comment: Those are properties and i can access them, but just not from the invoked method. The **purpose** of the question is to get an explaination how `Assemblies` work in this way.

Comment: I dont understand why this question got one upvote. He completey missunderstand what i meant and i wrote that just this invoked method cant access the values, which indicates that other classes can access the values. So it has nothing to do with initialising the static class,

Comment: How minimal is the code you're testing with?  The static class would be initialized in the executing instance if you have called any methods on it.  The assembly you're loading wouldn't have its static class's fields initialized unless you specifically called the method on that instance of the assembly.

Comment: I call a method from the static class earlier thats like i said not the problem that the static class isnt initialised in generell. So you indicate that the assembly from the dictionary has not been initialised, so all its members arent as well? So when i execute my programm it creates like an instance of my assembly and saves all the values in there as well?

Comment: "So when i execute my programm it creates like an instance of my assembly and saves all the values in there as well?"  Yes.  The currently running program is an assembly.  When you call `GetExecutingAssembly`, you get the assembly that's currently running.  Since you've already called a method on your static class, it will have already been initialized.  When you call `LoadFrom`, you'll get a new instance of your program that hasn't had anything initialized.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what i wanted to know.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to load the assembly, You just need the type to execute the static method using reflection, I use below to invoke my static method's that returns string.

```
 private static string ExecuteStaticMethod(Type objectType, string methodName, string defaultValue = null)
    {
        var retVal = defaultValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
        {
            var methodInfo = objectType.GetMethod(methodName);

            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                retVal = methodInfo.Invoke(null, null) as string;
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: I load the `Assembly` to get the type after that from a class located in this assembly. If i dont load the assembly i wont be able to get the type of the class, because the executung assembly at programm start is a different one than i want to invoke a method from.

Comment: are you doing GetValue(null) ? since it does not belong to any instance ?

Comment: Where should i call `GetValue()`? since i want to get the `Type`, its nonsense. And what does not belong to any instance?

Comment: sorry my friend , i might have had a problem understanding your problem. Good luck with it. Cannot afford to hep you with anymore nonsense.

Comment: Ye i guess you really didnt understand what i mean. I want to get an explanation about `Assemblies`, how they behave in this situation.